# How to combine facts , factTable and pre output views generated using Arelle's webservice api

Tags: xbrl, arelle

I have started exploring Arelle for XBRL parsing. I am calling Arelle's webservice Api through java to get the various views/outputs it can generate like facts, factTable, pre etc.

In the final output that I want I need all fields from facts file and few details from the pre file. I have written my Java code to do this, but I am stuck because I have no idea how to navigate from facts to pre. How can I combine these outputs? How are these views related, on what attributes ?

Answer (score 1):

Facts are related to presentation by means of the concept name (QName from an **XML** perspective, SQName from an Open Information Model perspective), like `us-gaap:Assets`.

The `facts` endpoint is a flat list of facts each having a concept name, while the `pre` endpoint organizes concepts, identified by their names, in a hierarchy.

The following drawing illustrates this mapping using **csv** as output. In **JSON**, for both *facts* and *pre*, the concept names are in a `name` field. In **XML**, they are in a `name` attribute. With Java, this requires parsing **XML** or **JSON** to build the appropriate objects and take it from there.

(This example was taken from [this SEC filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/21344/000002134414000008/0000021344-14-000008-index.htm))

[image: Mapping presentation to fact list]

Comment: Thank you very much. It definitely gives me a good start. Will get back with more questions if any.